Some details about Kirillov-Kostant Poisson bracket
Let $G$ be a finite dimensional Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. The Kirillov-Kostant Poisson bracket on $\mathfrak{g}^*$ is defined as $$\{\cdot ,\cdot \} :C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)\times C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)\to C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$$ by $$\{f,g\}(p):=p([f_{*p},g_{*p}])$$ where $f,g\in C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ and $f_{*p}$ denotes the differential of $f$ at $p\in \mathfrak{g}^*$.
My first question: We know that $$T_p\mathfrak{g}^*=\{\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\gamma (t):\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to \mathfrak{g}^* \; \text{is a path with}\; \gamma(0)=p\}$$ and
$$f_{*p}:T_p\mathfrak{g}^*\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}:\quad \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\gamma (t)\mapsto \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}f(\gamma (t)).$$
I know that $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$ and $T_p\mathfrak{g}^*\cong \mathfrak{g}^*$. So we can see $f_{*p}$ as $f_{*p}:\mathfrak{g}^*\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f_{*p}\in (\mathfrak{g}^*)^*$. On the other hand, $(\mathfrak{g}^*)^*\cong \mathfrak{g}$, hence $f_{*p}\in \mathfrak{g}$. My first problem is that how can we see $f_{*p}$ as real member of $\mathfrak{g}$. I mean how can we explicitly express $f_{*p}$ as $\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\gamma (t)$ where $\gamma$ is a path in $G$ with $\gamma (0)=e$ (we know that $\mathfrak{g}:=T_e G=\{\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\gamma (t):\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to G \; \text{is a path with}\; \gamma(0)=e\}$)?
My second question: If $X\in \mathfrak{g}$, is there a real function $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ such that $f_{*p}=X$? If so, what is its explicit formula?
Thank you very much for advance.
